# Eliminating a column from a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, loops, c#-4.0

I have a class as follows:

```
public class Entity 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Desc {get;set;}
}
```

I have a `List` of `Entity`:

```
List<Entity> ent = new List<Entity>()
{
    new Entity {Name ="A", ID =1},
    new Entity {Name ="B", ID = 2}
};
```

In the list , as we can observe the "**Desc**" value is blank for each of the object . Is there any way to find out the property Name , whose values are empty for all the objects in the List.

In this example , the output is "**Desc**" without using the for loops ,looping the objects and keeping a flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
var Properties = typeof(Entity).GetProperties()
                 .Where(propertyInfo => ent.All(entity => propertyInfo.GetValue(entity, null) == null))
                 .Select(c=>c.Name);
```

The `Properties` is an `IEnumerable` of `String` that is a `IEnumerable` of the `Properties`'s `Name` that their values are null for each of the object.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the properties of the type using [Type.GetProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx) method, then check that the property value in all of the items in the list is null using [LINQ All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) method and [PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
list<Entity> entities = ...;
foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(Entity).GetProperties())
{
    if(entities.All(entity => propertyInfo.GetValue(entity) == null))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} property is null in all of the items in the list", propertyInfo.Name);
    }
}
```